# Problem integrating what seems like a simple region.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to integrate a region from $0$ to $1$ on the $x$-axis and from $x$ to $1$ on the $y$-axis which is like an upside-down triangle with edges on $y = 1$ and $x = 0$ and $y = x$ so I set up the integral as:
$$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 dy\, dx $$
but when I plug the following code into Wolframalpha:

`integrate from 0 to 1 integrate from x to 1 1 dy dx`

it gives me the region in the first quadrant under the line $y = -x + 1$ ([link to Wolfram Alpha page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+1+integrate+from+x+to+1+1+dy+dx))

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the incorrect region is just a problem with Wolfram Alpha. (Note however  that $\frac{1}{2}$ is the correct value of the integral.) The correct region is of course

[image]

Comment: Thanks I got 1/2 for the answer too, my question was more on why is Wolframalpha's graph is so different from what I expected. Appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it doesn't matter since you are integrating half of a square.  More precisely, the upper half of the square with a line going cutting it in half diagonally.  You know that for a square, $Area=4*length.$ So, just take half of that and you get your integral which is equal to $\frac12$.